# Unexpected inferred type from Promise in Typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Code

```
export interface IA {
    Data: string
}

export class PromiseA extends Promise<IA> {

}

export class Component {
    public do(): void {
        // x is inferred as PromiseA
        const x = new PromiseA(ia => {});
        // y is inferred as Promise<IA>, why is that ?
        const y = this.shouldWork().then(yes => new PromiseA(ia => {}));
    }

    public shouldWork(): Promise<boolean> {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

Why is `y` inferred as `Promise<IA>` ? I expect it to be `PromiseA`

Is there any way to make `y` inferred as `PromiseA` ?

Also is there any resource where I can look up more about this ?

Comment: Your code doe not compile. You can't pass `null` to `new Promise` constructor.

Comment: @captain-yossarian it is a minimal reproducible example. In practice I pass in something else. The point is to illustrate why the inferrence works that way, so it's best to load it up in VSCODE and hover over the variables `x` and `y` to see it.
Anyway I'll amend the code to make it compilable.

Comment: The `.then()` is typed as returning a regular promise object. Which is correct, since when chaining `.then()` from a regular promise you still only get a regular promise regardless of what the callback returns.